# Lucene - Ngram: How to skip specific tokens during indexing

Tags: java, lucene, text-mining, n-gram

I am trying to index ngrams with only letters (i.e. all whitespace characters and punctuation removed) so that a user can find a document even if they omit space between the words during search. For that I have chosen a minimum size of 10 characters and a maximum of 20 characters. I am filtering the tokenizer with another custom filter that removes all the whitespace characters and punctuation and numbers (basically all characters except letters `a-z` and `A-Z`). The ngrams are generated and indexed fine except that when I am removing the unwanted characters from the string in the custom filter, the size of some ngrams is reduced to below the minimum size I have chosen and those are being indexed too. I wish to skip those particular tokens.

Here is my code:

```
public class NGramAnalyzer extends Analyzer {

    public NGramAnalyzer() {
        super();
    }

    @
    Override
    protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String fieldname) {
        Tokenizer source = new NGramTokenizer(10, 20);
        result = new CustomFilter(tokenizer);
        return new TokenStreamComponents(source, result);
    }



    public class CustomFilter extends TokenFilter {
        private CharTermAttribute termAttr = addAttribute(ChartermAttrribute.class);

        public CustomFilter(TokenStream tokenStream) {
            super(tokenStream);
        }

        @
        Override
        public boolean incrementToken() throws IOException {
            if (input.incrementToken()) {
                String s = String.valueOf(termAttr).replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", ""); //removing all characters except english letters
                this.termAttr.setEmpty().append(s);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

I have tried using `LengthFilter(result,10,20)` with the tokenstream obtained through customfilter but by using the lengthfilter it skips the entire document if the length of any of the ngrams from that document falls below 10 after the removal of unwanted characters.

How do I skip the indexing of ngrams of a document below a certain size while allowing others from the same document, after the length of the ngrams is changed in the custom filter? Any suggestions?